# What are differences between the words 'attribute' 'property' 'quality'

Tags: word-difference, definition, word-meaning

Question:

> Meaningwise in terms of this sentence and maybe some examples of yours, where these words can be used interchangeably and when won't?

Sentence:

> With this word we can describe some of her **attributes vs properties vs qualities**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **quality** - level of excellence or a distinctive attribute or characteristic possessed by someone or something.
2. **attribute** - a characteristic or quality of someone or something.
3. **property** - is something that is owned by someone or something or an attribute, quality, or characteristic of something *(not someone)*.

*"With this word we can describe some of her"* either **attributes** or **qualities** is fine if you are speaking about her and **properties** is fine if you are speaking about something she owns or possesses.

- With the word **"very"** we can describe her kindness. *(a quality)*
- With the word **"excellent"** we can describe her communicative skills. *(an attribute)*
- With the word **"plenty"** we can describe her books. *(a property)*

On other other hand.

Answer (score -1):

These words are, essentially, synonyms - different words with the same meaning.